# Construir docker image en un windows gitlab runner

Tags: docker, windows-server, gitlab-ci

Tengo un Windows Server 2019 donde hay configurado un runner de gitlab, este ya está relacionado con gitlab y ejecuta los pipelines. Pero como parte del pipeline necesito construir una imagen docker y hacer push de la misma, el problema es que no encuentro una imagen de windows que tenga docker instalado, al ejecutarlo por ejemplo con mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809_amd64 me devuelve: `docker : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,`

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809_amd64

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  
before_script:
  - docker login -u $env:REGISTRY_USER -p $env:REGISTRY_PASS $env:REGISTRY_HOST  

build-test:
  tags:
    - windows
  stage: build
  environment:
    name: test
  script:
    - docker build --pull --no-cache -t $env:REGISTRY_HOST/$env:PROJECT_PATH_LOW/$env:CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG:$env:VERSION -t $env:REGISTRY_HOST/$env:PROJECT_PATH_LOW/$env:CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG:latest -f TestSwarm/Dockerfile .
    - docker push $env:REGISTRY_HOST/$env:PROJECT_PATH_LOW/$env:CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG:$env:VERSION
    - docker push $env:REGISTRY_HOST/$env:PROJECT_PATH_LOW/$env:CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG:latest
  only:
    - master
```